# How to print File name in the same file?

Tags: linux

I have a file with around 5 lines and I want to have the file name printed at the end of every line.

```
for file in *.txt
do
  sed -i "1s/\$/${file%%.*}/" "$file"
done
```

The above code only writes file name in first line, I want to have file name in every line.

Comment: What shell? `bash`? `dash`? good ol' `sh`? Please [edit] to tag it.

Answer (score 1):

> The above code only writes file name in first line

This is what the `1` on the beginning of the `sed` command does: it is an [address](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Addresses-overview) that selects the lines processed by the command.

In your case, the `s` command applies only to the first line (because of `1` in front of the command). Remove the `1` from the command and it will apply to all lines of the file:

```
for file in *.txt
do
  sed -i "s/\$/${file%%.*}/" "$file"
done
```

Read more about `sed` at https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html.
Given that you have already learned `sed`, typing `man sed` on your terminal will refresh your memory about its commands.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit hacky, but it does the trick (bash):

```
filename=<filename>; len=$(wc -l $filename | cut -f1 -d' '); for i in $(seq $len); do echo $filename; done | paste $filename -
```

And this is cleaner, but needs python installed:

```
python -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(line.rstrip() + '\t' + sys.argv[1] for line in open(sys.argv[1])))" <filename>
```